# Checking for change in dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.6

I am using python 3.6, In the program I am writing is comparing a set of dictionaries for any difference. if found it updates a reference dictionary and clears the data.

On first start up it works and registers the first change but everyone after that it does not, and just displays the information but does not identify that it has changed. It acts as Πython is linking the two dictionaries together. Is there anything else Ι can do?

```
def Check_Data():
    global Ref_Readings
    print('Ref_Readings')
    print(Ref_Readings)
    print('Data')
    print(Data)
    a=Ref_Readings
    b=Data

    if (a != b):
        print('**************Updated Data')
        del Ref_Readings[:]
        Ref_Readings = Data
        #print(Ref_Readings)#
        Store_Readings()
    else:
        print('checking Settings')    
    del Data[:]
    print(Data)
```

Comment: *It acts as python is linking the two dictionaries together.*  When you say `Ref_Readings = Data`, you have two references pointing to the same dict.  Updates to one will affect the other.

Comment: Keep in mind that when you set Ref_Readings = Data, you are not copying. You are making it such that Ref_Readings and Data point to the same data structure in memory. This is probably the source of your misunderstanding.

Code comments:
The of 'print('**************Updated Data')' should go at the end of the if block, after you do the update. You want your prints to be accurate, if you want to leave the print there, make it read "Updating data" so that it's accurate. Also, the print in the else doesn't make sense. You've already checked the dicts at this point, no need for the else.

Comment: Correct the Line was more of a way for me to track and debug if it was working thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
Ref_Readings = Data  => a = b
```

Python uses references. If you want to have two different dictionaries you must do a copy.

```
import copy
Ref_Readings = copy.deepcopy(Data)
```

Comment: Thank you that was the trick. Something silly and simple as always

Answer (score 0):

list_a = list_b makes "memory pointer match". You have to use copy library.

Add to begin:

```
  import copy from copy
```

Change:

```
Ref_Readings = copy(Data)
```

you can also remove

```
a=Ref_Readings
b=Data
```

and change:

```
    if (Data != Ref_readings):
```